# periodic RTC interrupt in My own OS kernel

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel

I am currently programming a kernel in c++. So as the basic part of kernel i have implemented a interrupt handling module in my kernel and it works well. But it is not working for RTC IRQ8 interrupt.

This is the my code for enabling irq:

```
void IDT::enable_irq(unsigned short x, void (*handler)(), unsigned char control){
    current_mask &= ~(1<<x) ;   //Zero off the IRQ mask to enable
if (x>=8)
{
    current_mask &= ~(1<<2);
    set_int((x + SLAVE_VEC - 7),(unsigned long) handler, control);
}
else            //Sets the appropriate interrupt at the same time
{
    set_int((x + MASTER_VEC),(unsigned long) handler, control);
}
outb(PICMI, current_mask & 0xff);
outb(PICSI, (current_mask >> 8) & 0xff);
}
```

`set_int` is function to add interrupt entry in IDT.

It works great for keyboard interrupt if i call it as:

```
enable_irq(1,kbInt,INT_GATE|BITS_32|PRESENT|RING_2);
```

But if i called it for irq8 i.e. RTC then it is not working.

```
enable_irq(8,rtcInt,INT_GATE|BITS_32|PRESENT|RING_2);
```

It gives me error like: `An unhandled interrupt has occurred...`

Then i followd the instructions from this tutorial:
http://wiki.osdev.org/RTC

But what i want to do is, I want to generate periodic RTC interrupt and display time on screen on each interrupt. or i want to call a specific func on each rtc interrupt

So please can any one help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Basically what i want to do is, display a time on screen on each RTC interrupt.

Comment: How to enable IRQ8 and call a specific function on each interrupt in C++

Comment: You can edit your own question for updates.

Comment: If this is your own OS kernel, then you should know how to install some interrupt handler. Or is your question how to do that for your hardware? Then it might be at least useful to know what hardware this is about.

Comment: I have a module to install interrupt handler. And it works for keyboard.But it is not working with RTC. what i did is install an interrupt handler and enable irq8, but still not working. I am not able to find the what the actual problem is with the interrupts.

Comment: I got the problem,when i install irq8 interrupt handler, according to above func it will install on 41st entry of IDT.but when i enable irq8 it generates interrupt 70h, therefore it gives me unhandled interrupt according to IDT, so can any one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: 0x70 is the default interrupt for IRQ8 unless you've changed it by programming the PIC (see [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/PIC#Initialisation)). What is `SLAVE_VEC` defined as and how are you initializing the PIC?

Answer (score 1):

Your maths in your code is wrong.

```
if (x>=8) 
{ 
    current_mask &= ~(1<<2); 
    set_int((x + SLAVE_VEC - 7),(unsigned long) handler, control); 
}
```

will install a handler in position 0x41 in the IDT if SLAVE_VEC is 0x40 (as your comments imply) when surely you want to install it in position 0x40 since 0x40 is the interrupt which gets fired by the PIC for IRQ8 (again, assuming the PIC is configured to have a base of 0x40).

Your code should read:-

```
if (x>=8) 
{ 
    current_mask &= ~(1<<2); 
    set_int((x + SLAVE_VEC - 8),(unsigned long) handler, control); 
}
```

which will correctly configure the 0x40th IDT entry for IRQ8.